# How to add event listener to dynamic QTableWidgetItem in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, event-handling, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am a Python and Qt newbie...

I am working on a GUI program that shows a list of data using `QTableWidget` at the beginning.

The rows are inserted into the table using the `setItem()` method. They are `QTableWidgetItem` objects.

**Now I want to allow users to click-select a certain row (the `QTableWidgetItem`), and my program will populate a secondary `QTableWidget`.**

I have learnt that there is a thing called Signal and Slot. Am I going to use that?
There are also examples of using `installEventFilter()`, but it is not appropiate for the `QTableWidgetItem`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way for this would just be to use the `itemClicked`-signal of the QTableWidget:

```
def handle_item_clicked(tableItem):
    #the callback, called when an item is clicked, with the item as an argument
    #populate the secondary table in some way

#register the callback with the QTableWidget
yourTableWidget.itemClicked.connect(handle_item_clicked)
```

You could also use the `currentItemChanged` signal which gives you the current and previous selection (e.g. so you can clear or hide your secondary widget if the user deselects an item, in which case the current item will be None).

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't have "event listeners". As you mentioned, you do such things by [connecting](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qobject.html#connect-3) signals to slots.

For example:

```
QObject.connect(myTableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.foobar)
```

This will cause the method `self.foobar()` to be called when you click on `myTableWidget`. The foobar function could retrieve [which item is selected](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidget.html#selectedItems) and populate the second widget based on that.

Take note that in the last argument of `connect`, you don't use the parentheses (`foobar()`), just the method name!

Comment: Why do you use this archaic connection mechanism?

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Care to elaborate? Archaic in what sense??

Comment: @Kuba: I suppose he thinks the syntax used in l4mpi's answer is somehow better/newer. Wouldn't know myself, I've always used this in PyQt4 and it works perfectly for me.